# pymongo.MongoClient after os.fork

Tags: unix, connection, fork, pymongo

The [MongoReplicaSetClient docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.6.2/api/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.html) clearly states, that you cannot `fork` the process and use `MongoReplicaSetClient` in both processes.

The question: is it guaranteed that [MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.6.2/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html?highlight=mongoclient) would be working after a process fork? Or is it better to initiate separate connection to the database in each process independently?

As far as I know, the file descriptor [cannot be safely used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734354/817441) further after the process fork, because both processes share the same file description structure. However, these are not files, but network connections, wrapped into some python classes; so I have basically no idea whether the similar logic applies here, with `MongoClient`, or it is guaranteed to actually work correctly for some reason.

I do not also understand, will the network connection be closed if any child process exits before others or not (the simple writeup shows that it doesn't, but why and is it always so?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoClient 3.2 can work after fork(), but only on certain platforms. Here is a snippet from the doc: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing

> There are a few things to be aware of when using multiprocessing with
>   PyMongo. On certain platforms (defined here) MongoClient MUST be
>   initialized with connect=False if a MongoClient used in a child
>   process is initialized before forking. If connect cannot be False,
>   then MongoClient must be initialized AFTER forking.
>
> This is because CPython must acquire a lock before calling
>   getaddrinfo(). A deadlock will occur if the MongoClient‘s parent
>   process forks (on the main thread) while its monitor thread is in the
>   getaddrinfo() system call.
>
> PyMongo will issue a warning if there is a chance of this deadlock
>   occurring.