# Fork, pipe and file operations

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork, fstream

I have got a pipe to enable communication between 2 processes in forked program. It was created with pipe() call - http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe
. Everything goes right until I want to perform some file operations.

This code works:

```
pipe.writeBuffer(message.c_str(), message.length());
ofstream file;
file.open(name.c_str(), ios::app);
file << "stringData";    // put some data to file (many times)
```

But this one not:

```
ofstream file;
file.open(name.c_str(), ios::app);
pipe.writeBuffer(message.c_str(), message.length());
file << "stringData";    // put some data to file (many times)
```

In the second example there is no effect of "file << someStream" - I get the empty file.
What is wrong with that? Is it a problem with file descriptor? Pipe uses fd[0] - input and fd[1] - output. Maybe fstream uses also the same output file handler?

Here is the "working" sample:
http://pastebin.com/gJ4PbHvy

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define maxSize 64

using namespace std;

class Pipe
{
    public:
        Pipe()
        {
            pipe(fdesc);
        }

        ~Pipe() {}

        void writeBuffer(const char* message, size_t length)
        {
            close(fdesc[0]);
            write(fdesc[1], message, length);

        }

        void readBuffer()
        {
            char buffer[maxSize];
            close(fdesc[1]);
            size_t result = read(fdesc[0], &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            cout << buffer << endl;

        }

    private:
        int fdesc[2];

};

class Writer
{
    public:
        Writer(Pipe &obj)
        {
            pipe = obj;
        }

        ~Writer()
        {}

        void entry()
        {
            std::string name = "./myFile";
            ofstream file;
            file.open(name.c_str(), ios::app);

            std::string message = "hello world";
            pipe.writeBuffer(message.c_str(), message.length()+1);

            if (file.is_open())
            {
                file << "Hello World!" << endl;
                file.close();
            }
            else
            {
                perror("file.is_open()");
            }

            sleep(1);

        }

    private:
        Pipe pipe;

};


class Reader
{
    public:
        Reader(Pipe &obj)
        {
            pipe = obj;
        }

        ~Reader()
        {}


        void entry()
        {
            pipe.readBuffer();
            sleep(1);

        }

     private:
        Pipe pipe;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Pipe pipe;
    Reader reader(pipe);
    Writer writer(pipe);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) 
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) 
    {    
        // child process
        while(1)
            reader.entry();

    } 
    else 
    {
        // parent process
        while(1)
            writer.entry();

    }

}
```

Comment: what is somestream? What is message? the question does not make any sense.

Comment: You can consider this: file << "anything"; and in the second sample you will not find "anything" in the created file. The first sample works as expected.

Comment: What is `ios::app`? Do you verify that file was opened successfully? Are you sure the file is closed before you check file context? There can't be any connection between pipe and ofstream you are using.

Comment: Too little context to be answerable without crystal ball use. Random guess: flush the file.

Comment: and what is "someStream"?  Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (preferably in some place like ideone.com) and also post the entire sscce here.

Comment: @SergeyA can't is too strong. You can get both the pipe and the file using the same handle, but it takes work or serious dumb.

Comment: Ah. You mean a `std::ios_base::openmode`. and not coding an iPad App. That's good to know.

Comment: Neutrino, it might come as a surprise for you, but one is expected to properly prefix standard identifiers. @user4581301 got it faster than I did. On any rate, if you do not want my help, I will happily rescue myself.

Comment: @user4581301, not the handle, but the descriptor :). And I am honestly not sure how to have `std::ofstream` object to share the same file descriptor as one returned by `pipe` call - provided you do not invoke heavy artillery of using something like #define private public before including fstream.

Comment: @SergeyA I've crossed descriptors once on Linux, and it was the result of serious dumb. If I can do it by being stupid, I figure someone smart can do it on purpose.

Comment: By opening `file` before forking, you now have two processes pointing to the same file. I'm not sure what will happen in this case, but it looks like these people have a few ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733481/can-anyone-explain-a-simple-description-regarding-file-descriptor-after-fork

Comment: @user4581301 You might be right...

Comment: Unfortunately not, I changed the code this way http://pastebin.com/PLZisw5Y but still have the same effect.

Comment: Rats. Got nothing for you then, friend.

Comment: The posted program on each run does write one line `Hello World!` into `myFile`. The pastebin pages are no longer available. So, your issue isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

With the posted program, the described issue of getting an empty file isn't reproducible, since on each run it does write one line `Hello World!` into `myFile`, but this still shows the error, because you intend to write one line every second. The reason is the `close(fdesc[0])` in `writeBuffer()`: While it is correct to close the read end of the pipe *once* in the writer process, it is incorrect to do it every time `writeBuffer()` is called, as that file descriptor can (and in the case at hand, does) have been reused after the first `close()` for another file (here the file `ofstream file`), which is after it closed instead of the (already closed) pipe, so that nothing can be written into the file. Fix: Arrange your program to close the pipe end only once, e. g. by changing

```
            close(fdesc[0]);
```

to

```
            if (0 <= fdesc[0]) close(fdesc[0]), fdesc[0] = -1;
```