# If a parent opens a file, then forks a child, does the child have access to the open file? (C programming)

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, parent, child-process

so I have a question regarding what a child process has access to.

If a parent open()s a file, and then fork()s a child, does the child process have access to the open file, or would it need to open the file itself? Would it be possible to have access to the already open file through shared memory between the processes? (C programming)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733481/can-anyone-explain-a-simple-description-regarding-file-descriptor-after-fork

Comment: How would you expect a `pipe` to work if the child *didn't* keep the same file descriptors as the parent?

Comment: `fork()` creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. The new process, referred to as the child, is an **exact duplicate** of the calling process, referred to as the parent with some exception. Here's the man page for [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer yes.

You can read more about it here:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

As it is said there, the child process is an exact duplicate of the parent process except
       for the following points:

```
   *  The child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not
      match the ID of any existing process group (setpgid(2)).

   *  The child's parent process ID is the same as the parent's process
      ID.

   *  The child does not inherit its parent's memory locks (mlock(2),
      mlockall(2)).

   *  Process resource utilizations (getrusage(2)) and CPU time counters
      (times(2)) are reset to zero in the child.

   *  The child's set of pending signals is initially empty
      (sigpending(2)).

   *  The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent
      (semop(2)).

   *  The child does not inherit process-associated record locks from
      its parent (fcntl(2)).  (On the other hand, it does inherit
      fcntl(2) open file description locks and flock(2) locks from its
      parent.)

   *  The child does not inherit timers from its parent (setitimer(2),
      alarm(2), timer_create(2)).

   *  The child does not inherit outstanding asynchronous I/O operations
      from its parent (aio_read(3), aio_write(3)), nor does it inherit
      any asynchronous I/O contexts from its parent (see io_setup(2)).

   The process attributes in the preceding list are all specified in
   POSIX.1.  The parent and child also differ with respect to the
   following Linux-specific process attributes:

   *  The child does not inherit directory change notifications
      (dnotify) from its parent (see the description of F_NOTIFY in
      fcntl(2)).

   *  The prctl(2) PR_SET_PDEATHSIG setting is reset so that the child
      does not receive a signal when its parent terminates.

   *  The default timer slack value is set to the parent's current timer
      slack value.  See the description of PR_SET_TIMERSLACK in
      prctl(2).

   *  Memory mappings that have been marked with the madvise(2)
      MADV_DONTFORK flag are not inherited across a fork().

   *  The termination signal of the child is always SIGCHLD (see
      clone(2)).

   *  The port access permission bits set by ioperm(2) are not inherited
      by the child; the child must turn on any bits that it requires
      using ioperm(2).

   Note the following further points:

   *  The child process is created with a single thread—the one that
      called fork().  The entire virtual address space of the parent is
      replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes,
      condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of
      pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that
      this can cause.

   *  After a fork(2) in a multithreaded program, the child can safely
      call only async-signal-safe functions (see signal(7)) until such
      time as it calls execve(2).

   *  The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
      descriptors.  Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same
      open file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file
      descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two file
      descriptors share open file status flags, file offset, and signal-
      driven I/O attributes (see the description of F_SETOWN and
      F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

   *  The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open message
      queue descriptors (see mq_overview(7)).  Each file descriptor in
      the child refers to the same open message queue description as the
      corresponding file descriptor in the parent.  This means that the
      two file descriptors share the same flags (mq_flags).

   *  The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open directory
      streams (see opendir(3)).  POSIX.1 says that the corresponding
      directory streams in the parent and child may share the directory
      stream positioning; on Linux/glibc they do not.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the same file descriptor.  No need for shared memory.

It would kind of work using a stdio `FILE*` but I would no advise doing so for files you plan to write to, as buffering in the two separate processes would lead to unexpected and confusing results.

To prevent this sharing of file descriptors - if you want to - you can of course call `close()` on the file descriptor as soon as the `fork()` call returns 0.