# creating 3 pipes from the same 2 dimension array

Tags: c, pipe

```
int fd[3][2]; pipe(fd[0]); pipe(fd[1]); pipe(fd[2]);
```

By doing this, am I creating 3 pipes, `fd[0]`, `fd[1]` and `fd[2]`? 
And if that's the case, will it work like this, because I got confused:

1. pipe `fd[0]`, read from `fd[0][0]` and write to `fd[0][1]`
2. pipe `fd[1]`, read from `fd[1][0]` and write to `fd[1][1]`
3. pipe `fd[2]`, read from `fd[2][0]` and write to `fd[2][1]`

Comment: Yes it will work exactly as you think.

Comment: Yes, this will work exactly like that. A few days ago I posted an answer that involved creating an array of 26 pipes, I did it exactly like that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547996/creating-seperate-child-function-for-counting-each-letter-in-a-file/48554373#48554373 for reference.